# error when adding compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-gradle-3.0

I have an error when I put

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
```

[image]

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "eyaa.compsproject"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

why red in line

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

when using

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'
```

Comment: Your Firebase versions need to match Google play

Comment: Also, if you only need GCM, then only add that one. It's unlikely that you need all the Google play services

Answer (score 0):

The play service and firebase version needed to be same,
Please replace with below code and check.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
```

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'

Same too I have red line in  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

Comment: Same too I have red line in compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1' I have to use  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'